# Why are my Firefox Menu Arrows Enlarged? How do I fix them?

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1

I recently formatted my laptop (Windows 8.1 RTM) and reinstalled a lot of software from scratch. Once I finished setting up Firefox, I noticed the "fly-out" arrows of the Firefox menu are ridiculously enlarged.  This is the case for all menus within firefox, including any drop-down menus for my extensions.

Here is an example:

[image]

And another:

[image]

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I reset the appearance to the way it's supposed to look, normally?

I am running the latest release of Firefox; at the time of this writing, v23.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have your DPI (dots per inch) setting set to a larger than default value, which can happen automatically during installation of Windows, if it thinks you're using a high-density display.

I just changed to a larger DPI setting myself and I can confirm that the arrows end up blown out of proprtion... it seems that Firefox just doesn't handle scaling them up properly.

So if you actually *want* to use a high DPI setting, I'm afraid you'll have to either deal with it, or install a custom theme.

You can change your DPI by searching for "Make text and other items larger or smaller" in the Start screen.

Comment: Ah-ha, that fixed it.  Thanks very much. It appeared to have a default value of "Medium (125%)."  I set it back to 100 and everything looked good again.  I'll have to see if anyone reported this as an issue to Mozilla yet.